# Can this colpitt get more efficient?

Tags: oscillator

I am testing many solutions for wireless power transfer, among the solutions i am evalutating all of them (but one) are based on switching FETs (serie resonant halfbridge, class E, push pull..) so very good efficiency, but to eliminate this one (colpitt oscillaotr) my supervisor is asking me for good arguments because it has the advantage of being the cheapest solution. 
For this exact circuit i simulalted, (with a secondary coil coupled to L1) and a load behind and i have less than 8% efficiency for a huge load range. (i didn't change a thing since i have a relatively poor background in analog electronics. in a famous MIT wireless powertransfer paper, they had 80%.

So my question is:  How Can this oscillator be more efficient (with a more optimal design), or is there some strong arguments like : No there will always be huge losses in the biasing circuit or in the transistor because it is will always conduct current with non null Vce.. or somethign like that

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The emitter resistor will be biased at around 1 volt DC and therefore the current it draws is about 0.5 mA. This current also flows through the transistor. The transistor collector sits at 6 V (on average) so the steady power consumed by transistor and emitter resistor is 6V * 0.5 mA = 2.7 mW.

If the load only receives (say) 0.25 mW then the efficiency is bound to be low at less than 10% and this doesn't account for the AC losses in the circuit.

You can't take big power from this type of circuit because it will fail to oscillate if the loading on the coil is too great. You might be able to take up to 1 mW i.e. it is not great for a device to transfer power inductively.

Comment: Why does he have to be biased at 1Vdc ? how do we chose the voltage to be bias at? can we chose a lower voltage?

Comment: also the fact that it is biased means that there will always be a DC current entring the collector right? but simulation show a two perfectly sinusoidal currents in the C1 and the L1 ! and with KCL this is illogical, what am i missing?

Comment: A dc current passes thru the coil if that makes any sense.

Comment: yes but that's a result of the biasing but can it work without biasing?

Comment: No it won't work without biasing. Transistors have to be biased to put them into the correct area of their characteristic to do the job they are intended to do.